# Prove that if $H = \langle a\rangle , |H| = n$ then $a^n = e$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am to prove that if $H = \langle a\rangle, |H| = n$ then $a^n=e$; $H<G$ where $G$ is a group. So what I know is:
$$H=\{a^0, a^1, a^2,...,a^{n-1}\}$$
Of course $a^0=e$, where $e$ is the neutral element in both group $G$ and subgroup $H$.
I don't know how can I show that $a^n=e$, where $n$ is the smallest natural number with this property.

Comment: If you already know that the first $n-1$ powers of $a$ are distinct, then consider the following: $a^n\in H$ so $a^n=a^m$ for some $0\leq m\leq n$ and the rest follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a^n \ne e$ then what *does* it equal?

It must equal some $a^i$ so $a^i = a^n$ of some $0 < i < n$.  So $e= (a^{-1})^ia^i = (a^{-1})^i a^n = a^{n-i}$.

Can you see where that gets us?  Let $j = n- i >0$ so $a^j = e; 0 < j < n$.

For every $k; j \le k < n-1$ then $a^k = a^{k-j}$.  So the only distinct elements of the set are $\{e, a , ....., a^{j-1}\}$.  Something is really , really wrong here.

Comment: I see the contradiction but I don't really get why $a^j = e$ implies that the only distinct elements of the set are $\{e, a, ... a^{j-1} \}$?

Comment: If $k > j$ then $a^k = a^{k-j + j} = a^{k -j}a^j = a^{k-j}*e = a^{k-j}$  So $a^k$ is not distinct.

Comment: Thanks! I think that I got in now :)

Answer (score 3):

By the definition of a group, being closed under the group operation we have that $a^n\in H$. Suppose that $a^n\neq e$. We will get a contradiction:

$a^n\neq e$ implies that $a^n = a^r$ for some $0<r<n$ since $|H|=n$. Hence $a^{n-r}=a^k=e$. So we have that the group $H$ consists of the elements $e,a,a^2,\dots, a^{k-1}$ where $k<n$. This is because $H$ is generated by $a$ which means that it consists of elements of the form $a^j$, i.e. $$H=\{e, a,\dots, a^r,\dots a^{k-1}, a^k=e, a^{k+1}=a,a^{k+2}=a^2,\dots, a^{n}=a^{r},\dots\}$$

So $H$ consists of at most $k$ distinct elements, namely $|H|\leq k < n$. Contradiction since $H$ has order $n$ by assumption.

Comment: I don't understand why $a^k = e \rightarrow H = \{ e, a, ..., a^{k-1}\}?$

Comment: @Hendrra The definition of a group generated by $a$ means that all its elements are of the form $a^j$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $H=\langle a\rangle$, the homomorphism $\varphi_a\colon\mathbb{Z}\to H$ defined by $\varphi_a(k)=a^k$ is surjective.

The homomorphism theorem yields that $|\mathbb{Z}/\ker\varphi_a|=|H|=n$. Therefore $\ker\varphi_a=n\mathbb{Z}$, by the standard classification of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, $a^n=e$.